# jQuery fade in/out between divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade

I have this code:

```
var next = null;
    var outer = jQuery('.banner .container');
    var current = outer.find('.banner-word:first');
    current.fadeIn();
    function fade() {
        if (current.next('div.banner-word').length > 0) {
            next = current.next('div.banner-word');
        } else {
            next = outer.find('.banner-word:first');
        }
        current.fadeOut();
        next.fadeIn();
        current = next;
        setTimeout(fade, 11000);
    }
    // start the process
    fade();
```

A few problems with it - 1) It seems to ignore the first banner-word div 2) On load it shows quickly shows the first 2 banner-word divs and then starts with the second banner-word div

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Seeing the html would be helpful.

Comment: HTML:    <div class="banner">
 <div class="container">
   <span>*****</span>
   <div id="b1" class="banner-word">knows people</div>
   <div id="b2" class="banner-word">knows recruitment</div>
   <div id="b3" class="banner-word">knows business</div>
 </div>
 <div class="overlay">
 </div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
if (current.next('div.banner-word').length > 0) {
    next = current.next('div.banner-word');
} else {
    next = outer.find('.banner-word:first');
}
```

to:

```
if (current.next().is('div.banner-word')) {
    next = current.next();
} else {
    next = outer.find('.banner-word:first');
}
```

Edit: 
try adding a delay to the initial fade() call.
Change

```
fade();
```

to

```
setTimeout(fade, 5000);
```

Comment: Better - so although the first two now don't quickly show it still doesn't start with b1...